# Use Mat::at<Vec3i> Point not assing the correct pixel

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I usually find all the answers to the problems that usually came out to me, unfortunately I couldn't find the solution in this case. I have the following code

```
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ){
   Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
   drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
   rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
    drawing.at<Vec3i>(centroid[i])[0]=color[0];
    drawing.at<Vec3i>(centroid[i])[1]=color[1];
    drawing.at<Vec3i>(centroid[i])[2]=color[2];
    circle(drawing, centroid[i], 5, color, 3,8,0);
    cout<<centroid[i]<<endl;
    imshow( "Contours", drawing );
    waitKey(0);
 }
```

And the problem is that the centroid is not place were it should be. The points are on the same height but wrong width. I have already check the "centroid" using the circle drawing  for each contours and the points are O.K.

Can some one help me on the matter

Comment: Thanks it worked, I knew I had done something wrong, now I found out what was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to assign 3*32 bits to a field that is only 3*8 bits in size. You defined the matrix to be of type `CV_8UC3`, so you should use `drawing.at<Vec3b>(...)` (where `b` stands for unsigned char). You can find the various typedefs [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#vec).

You can read `CV_xxtCn` as

- xx: number of bits
- t: type (F = floating point type, S = signed integer, U = unsigned integer)
- n: number of channels